# Similar to hash values but something that returns an int

Tags: firefox, hash, firefox-addon, dht

Using the hash function MD5 on a string creates a very long value, and it creates the same value for the same string every time. Now, my question is: is there a way to do something similar, like give it a string and it returns the same integer every time, and also the integers that it returns for different string are inside a specific interval. What i mean is something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg).

Ex: Give it "Mary had a little lamb." and it returns the value 10. Give the same string, it returns 10 again.

Please do ask, in case i wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Note that it will not be unique.

Comment: Even if the string is unique?
In fact, even if it's not, is there a function for this?

Comment: There are 2^32 possible ints.  There are an infinite number of possible strings.  What do _you_ think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a "hash function". Look it up on Wikipedia.

MD5 is one kind of hash function. Most MD5 implementations return a string, but that string is just a representation of a (LARGE) integer. You can take an MD5 hash, and then use as many of the low-order bits as you need to get an integer of the desired size. If the desired range is not a power of 2, you will need to do a modulo operation to get it into the desired range.

Also, virtually every modern programming language has a built-in function for hashing strings, which returns an integer. In Java, it's String.hashCode(). In Ruby, it's String#hash.

In this case, the language is Javascript, which (I was shocked to learn) doesn't seem to have something like this built in. This is String.hashCode() from the Java platform (perhaps you can port it to Javascript):

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
if (h == 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;
    int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: "You can take an MD5 hash, and then use as many of the low-order bits as you need to get an integer of the desired size." Could you elaborate please? A simple example would be great if possible. (Also, by "using as many of low order bits as i need" won't it make it NOT unique?)

Comment: Hmm, i thought the function maps a unique key to a unique string. Different string,different key. With a "failure" rate which is too low to be significant.

Comment: Hashes are by necessity not unique, as @SLaks explained. The whole idea, though, is that the chances of a "collision" (getting the same number for 2 strings) should be *very* small. If you use a 32-bit integer to hold the hash, there are up to 2^32 possible hash values. If the hashing algorithm is good, the chance of getting any one of those values should be roughly equal. So the chances of getting the same hash value for 2 arbitrary strings should be about 1 in 2^32. If you use 64 bits for the hash, well... you might never get a collision in the expected lifetime of the universe.

Comment: Andrei, what language are you using? Just use the built-in function for hashing strings, whatever it is. It maps unique strings to unique keys *"with a failure rate which is too small to be significant"*. (That last sentence is very important.)

Comment: I am developing an extension for mozilla firefox. The language is javascript, but i can use the C++ classes from firefox's platform. I'm trying to use the Chord protocol in which i need to hash the ip+port of nodes (computers) and then place them (or at least consider them as being placed) on a circle in an ASCENDING FASHION. I need to be able to compare hash values among themselves, thus knowing where to place them on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lower bytes of an MD5 hash. You have to consider that JavaScript (at least in Firefox 9) can use something like 48 bits (6 bytes) to store exact integer numbers, the length of an MD5 hash on the other hand is 128 bits (16 bytes). So you will necessarily have more hash collisions than you would normally get with MD5. But still:

```js
function toHashCode(str)
{
  // Convert string to an array of bytes
  var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(str);

  // Create MD5 hash
  var hashEngine = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/security/hash;1"]
                             .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsICryptoHash);
  hashEngine.init(hashEngine.MD5);
  hashEngine.update(array, array.length);
  var hash = hashEngine.finish(false);

  // Turn the first 6 bytes of the hash into a number
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    result = result * 256 + hash.charCodeAt(i);
  return result;
}

alert(toHashCode("test"));  // Displays 265892827251497
alert(toHashCode("Mary had a little lamb."));   // Displays 117938552300214
```